# Does a static variable inside a function ever go out of scope?

Tags: c

While reading this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999737/how-to-find-multiple-missing-integers-in-an-array-using-c) I noticed an interesting scenario.  The question has a function which is only called once:

```
int* missing_elements(int arr[], int len){

    static int arr2[]={0};

    for(int i=0,j=1; i < 7; i++,j++){
        if(arr[i] != j){
            arr2[i]=j;
            if(arr[i] == j++){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr2;
}
```

The function is returning a pointer to an array that is defined as static within the function.  I'm curious about how the scope of `arr2[]` is handled.  If `arr2[]` was defined as not static then then it would fall out of scope and you couldn't assume that the returned pointer would point to valid data.

My question is since `arr2` is static will it always be in scope even if the function that defines it will never be called again.  Is this undefined behavior or can we assume that it never loses scope?

Comment: The array `arr2` has static *duration* (not "scope"), and so lasts as long as the program does.  (It never goes away.)

Comment: Scope is something the compiler worries about, it is not in scope outside of the function.  Storage is something the processor worries about, the static keyword ensures it is stable outside of the function.  Whether that storage is valid when you use threads is what you get to worry about, the C language spec doesn't help with that.

Comment: Your example is problematic, because it has undefined behavior due to out-of-bounds access anyway. (except for special intputs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is since arr2 is static will it always be in scope even if
>   the function that defines it will never be called again. Is this
>   undefined behavior or can we assume that it never loses scope?

If we look at [`draft N2310 - 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf#subsection.6.2.4)

You'll see that it states (emphasis mine)

> 3. An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class
>      specifier
>      _Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier **static**, has *static storage duration*. Its
>      **lifetime is the entire execution of the program** and its stored value
>      is **initialized only once**, prior to program startup.

Comment: Good link to the C11 pdf. You can also deep-link to the [C18 Standard (draft n2130) - 6.2.4 Storage Duration of Objects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf#subsection.6.2.4) or you can link to the html [C11 Standard (draft n1570) - 6.2.4 Storage Duration of Objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4). What you have is fine, the deep-links just allow jumping directly to the section of interest.